# Using React in Codepen but not getting anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, codepen

I'm new to React and Codepen but just started trying it out. Somehow the examples that I copied from elsewhere that I know should work doesn't give me anything in Codepen. Thought I must've set up things wrong I ended up forking other people's code on Codepen and trying my code there and it still doesn't work.

Here's an example of what I'm trying: https://codepen.io/hensy8586/pen/MWyoGLR. It's a simple code that should return three clickable buttons but I see nothing in the output window other than blank, and I'm not getting any error messages.

There are a few other error messages I encountered that confuse me:

- I've also seen (sometimes) an error message saying I should import React and ReactDOM but I've seen plenty other codes that work without one.
- I also encountered error that says `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`, which goes away after I add require.js script. But I've noticed many other code in Codepen that runs okay without require.js added.

I appreciate if someone can help me understand these better. Thanks.

Comment: In my opinion the best web tool for React is https://codesandbox.io/. Try there, it always shows you all errors and helps to add extra dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CHANGE THIS:

```
function Clicker({ handleClick }) {
  return <div>
    <button onClick={(e) => {handleClick('A');}}>A</button>
    <button onClick={(e) => {handleClick('B');}}>B</button>
    <button onClick={(e) => {handleClick('C');}}>C</button>
  </div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Clicker handleClick={(letter) => 
    {console.log(`${letter} clicked`);}} />,
  document.getElementById('root');
```

TO THIS:

```
function Clicker({ handleClick }) {
  return <div>
    <button onClick={(e) => {handleClick('A');}}>A</button>
    <button onClick={(e) => {handleClick('B');}}>B</button>
    <button onClick={(e) => {handleClick('C');}}>C</button>
  </div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Clicker handleClick={(letter) => 
    {console.log(`${letter} clicked`);}} />
  ,document.getElementById('root')
); //<-- Oops!
```

---

**Culprit:** Missing `);` at the end.

[Working Codepen](https://codepen.io/kostasx/pen/vYGZrNe?editors=1010)

---

I suggest you follow this [guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#add-react-in-one-minute) to set up a working React web page or use [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).

Both ways, will help you better debug errors and work in an environment where no other framework, libraries or code runs, e.g. Codepen. This is the preferred way IMHO for non-experienced React users.

Also, prefer the `development` versions of the library instead of the `production` version. Switch to the `production` version, only when your app is tested and ready for deployment.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! My stupidity again. lol. Interesting how Codepen would have all kinds of errors and not telling me there was a syntax error. Makes sense on the best practice.